# IE Javascript error checking on Microsoft virtual PC

Tags: javascript, xhtml, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I'm checking IE 6 issues of a xhtml css page on locally using VPC image of Microsoft Virtual PC.

IE6 showing a JavaScript error. In VPC image i doesn't have MS Visual Studio installed.

[image]

Web-page has many JavaScript. How to know from Which script and where in script this error is coming?. I can know on My PC with the help of Visual Studio debug function. but not on VPC image.

Where will be this Line 22 ?

**Note:** Error is only coming in IE.

Comment: Open `index.html` and go to line 22. Could you paste code from that line in your question?

Comment: you mean no line 22 in my dreamweaver.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: IE always reports the web page name, even if the line 22 in question is in another script file. The old-and-nasty way to find out which script file it is, on a machine where you can't install a proper debugger, is to add a load of blank lines to the start of each script. By adding a different number of blank lines to each, and looking at how much the reported line increases, you can deduce which script is to blame.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, @bobince - I found the problem with the help of "Microsoft Script Debugger" and problem was not in html source it was in line no. 22 of attached file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2f465be0-94fd-4569-b3c4-dffdf19ccd99&displaylang=en) is OK if you don't want to go all out and install a Visual Studio variant on the computer.

Also, try the site under Firefox or another browser.  Chances are that the other browsers are also getting the JavaScript error but are letting it slide.  In Firefox, take a look at the JavaScript console to make sure you're not missing anything.

Comment: Thanks i installed Microsoft Script Debugger and it's working as i want. I just searched on google for this and found and followed this article to install http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to install IE Dev Toolbar, I'm pretty sure the IE6 version is still around.  That allows for step-through and debugging of scripts as well.

Comment: I have installed Developer toolbar. How to reach at source of error

Answer (score 0):

The old built-in IE debugger is all but useless. Install Visual Studio Express on the virtual machine.

Comment: Other debuggers exist, I've never found them to be as good as VS (when it comes to IE specific JS issues)